# how to use View of One DB in another DB in same server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

I have View V_empmaster in MYemp database in Sqlserver2008 server, Now I want to use V_empmaster view in MASTERDB database in Same server. 
My query is : 
 select * from dbo.MasterDB.V_empmaster;

but SQL Execution Error message is displayed 
        Error source: .NetSqlclientDataProvider
        Error Message: Invalid objectname 'dbo.V_empmaster'

Anyone help me out what is my mistake even if it is silly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts of a name are `server.database.schema.object`. You've got schema and database the wrong way around:

```
select * from MasterDB.dbo.V_empmaster
```

Answer (score 1):

When you refer view from another database in the same server, you should use three part object qualifier:

```
-- set context to MYemp db
use MYemp
GO
-- access V_empmaster data in MYemp db
select * from dbo.V_empmaster
GO
-- switch context to MASTERDB
use MASTERDB
GO
-- to access V_empmaster from MYemp, three part qualifier
-- ([dbName].[schemaName].[objectName]) is used
select * from MYemp.dbo.V_empmaster
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution! It is working when I executed it as QUERY. I tried to copy in View of MASTERDB but getting error